# Can someone explain why Div hiding behind other Divs in HTML Layout?

Tags: html, css

I was wondering if someone could explain to me why this is happening.  Sorry I am new to CSS/HTML.  I am working on creating and HTML layout for a basic page, currently I have three Divs.  I want one container on the left (id= leftside) with 50% width and another on the right (id=rightside) with 50% width and the third container (id=narrow) below both of them at 100% width.

So currently my third div gets hidden underneath the first two unless I add the property 'top: 50%;' to that div. Can someone please explain why this is happening?  I thought that since the space is already taken by my other two divs  that I would not have to use the 'top' property in order for the third div to display.  Why is it being hidden by the other divs?

Here is my HTML code:

```
<body>
    <div id="leftside"></div>
    <div id="rightside"> </div>
    <div id="narrow"></div>
</body>
```

Here is my CSS code:

```
#leftside{
width: 50%;
height: 50%;
background-color: blue;
float:left;
}

#rightside{
width: 50%;
height: 50%;
background-color: red;
float:right;
}

 #narrow{
width:100%;
height:20%;
background-color:black;
}
```

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

Comment: Thanks for the replies everyone, it makes sense to me now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you do use the float for the element then don't forget to clear them.

For easier I always use `overflow:hidden;` to the parent div:

```
<div class="parent">
   <div id="leftside"></div>
   <div id="rightside"> </div>
   <div id="narrow"></div>
</div>

.parent{overflow:hidden;}
```

So now, you know the key reason of hiding?

Comment: Using overflow on the parent won't help when the element that you want to clear is inside the same parent.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't get you. Could you please re-phrase?

Comment: The element with `id="narrow"` will still be behind the floating elements, because it's inside the element that has `overflow:hidden`.

Answer (score 2):

Because the first two divs have set floats so they are taken out from the "normal" flow, while the last remains the same and isn't affected by the previous two.

To be affected you can either set float also to the last element, or clear the float.

```
#narrow {
  width:100%;
  height:20%;
  background-color:black;
  clear: both;
}
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float#Clearing_floats for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I always create a spacer div and use it whenever I need to clear any previous floats or coding. This is specially useful when I have a ton of divs within a parent div.

```
.spacer {
clear:both;
border:none;
width:100%;
}

*other divs above*

<div class="spacer">&nbsp;</div>

*other divs below*
```